# Memo field from DBF file only returns a few characters using VFP OLE DB Provider for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, oledb, visual-foxpro, dbase

I am developing a Winforms app that reads info from a `.DBF` database.
I use the `VFP OLE DB Provider` for regular queries and it works just fine.

But I have come to a point where I need to read an image stored in a `Memo` field. If I do a regular `SELECT` query to get the field I only get a string with the value of

> ÿØÿà

Which I believe it's part of the metadata for a JPE image but obviously I am missing some info.

What I need to do is extract the info from the database and display it in a `PictureBox` in a form.

This is the code I use to read info from the DB:

```
public DataTable SendQuery(string query)
{
    try
    {
        Conn = new OleDbConnection
        {
            ConnectionString = "Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=C:\Data;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;Collating Sequence=machine;"
        };
        Conn.Open();

        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, Conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        Conn.Close();
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
    catch (OleDbException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message + "\nWith error" + e.ErrorCode, "Error de base de datos");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error general");
    }
    finally
    {
        Conn.Close(); //Just to be sure
    }
    return null;
}
```

As I mentioned earlier, this works fine when reading texts and numbers, (even a memo field in which I store large texts) but it's just not working with this particular image in a  Memo field.

Just as a note, I am sure that nor the database or the fields are corrupt.

Comment: I suspect it's truncating the data at the first 0x00 byte in the data, which in all the sample .JPGs I've looked at, is the 5th byte.  Is there any way you can try it with the FoxPro table using a field of data type BLOB rather than MEMO?

Comment: Is that part of the actual memo data, or is that the data in the field in the dbf, which is an offset into the memo file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default a memo field is treated as a string with OleDb. In C# however, unlike the documentation, a string is a ASCIIZ string. It wouldn't read past seeing a \x00 character. You can cast the field to a blob and thus read as a binary value. Here is an example:

VFP code for creating sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE c:\temp\imageData FREE (id i, ext c(3), filedata m)
INSERT INTO c:\temp\imageData (id, ext, filedata) VALUES (1,'jpg',FILETOSTR('C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\arm64\AccChecker\AccChecker_HelpFiles\image001.jpg'))
INSERT INTO c:\temp\imageData (id, ext, filedata) VALUES (2,'jpg',FILETOSTR('C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\arm64\AccChecker\AccChecker_HelpFiles\image002.jpg'))
INSERT INTO c:\temp\imageData (id, ext, filedata) VALUES (3,'jpg',FILETOSTR('C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\arm64\AccChecker\AccChecker_HelpFiles\image003.jpg'))
```

Code to read from VFP:

```
void Main()
{
    var table = SendQuery("select id, ext, cast(filedata as blob) as filedata from imageData");

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        var bytes = (byte[])row["filedata"];
        var id = (int)row["id"];
        var ext = (string)row["ext"];

        File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(@"c:\temp", $"test_image{id}.{ext.Trim()}"),bytes);
    }
}

public DataTable SendQuery(string query)
{
    string cnStr = @"Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=C:\Temp;";
    try
    {
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        new OleDbDataAdapter(query, cnStr).Fill(tbl);
        return tbl;
    }
    catch (OleDbException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message + "\nWith error" + e.ErrorCode, "Error de base de datos");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error general");
    }
    return null;
}
```

PS: You could have used Linq and thus you wouldn't have such a problem (Tom Brothers has a driver for VFP - [Linq To VFP](https://github.com/tombrothers/LINQtoVFP)).

Comment: Works exactly how I expected and it's so simple. Thanks a lot!